# React Native Android App fails to compile on adding React Native WebView

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native-webview

I am trying to introduce react-native-webview in my app to show web content. This works well with IOS.
However, the android app fails to compile.

I have also performed steps highlighted here - https://engineering.brigad.co/demystifying-react-native-modules-linking-964399ec731b.

To Reproduce:

- Setup a new React Native project using `npx react-native init TestProject`
- Add React Native Web Dependency - `yarn add react-native-webview`
- Perform Manual Linking using the steps in https://engineering.brigad.co/demystifying-react-native-modules-linking-964399ec731b.
- Start Android App - `npx react-native run-android`
- Expected behavior:
- The Android App should compile successfully

Current Behavior:
The compilation fails with the error -

`A problem occurred configuring project 'react-native-webview'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration 'react-native-webview:classpath'.
Could not download gradle-7.0.4.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.
0.4)
Could not get resource 'https://di.google.com/d|/android/ maven2/com/android/tools/build/ gradle/Z.0.4/gradle-7.0.4.jar'
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/d|/android/maven2/ com/android/tools/build/gradle/ 7.0.4/gradle-7.0.4 jar'.
Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/142.250.180.14,dl.google.com/ 2a00:1450:4009:81d:0:0:0:200e]
failed: No route to host (connect failed)`

Environment:

OS: MacOs
OS version: Ventura 13.3
react-native version: 0.71.7
react-native-webview version: 12.0.2
Note : The issue occurs irrespective of whether manual linking steps are performed.

Please can you help with the above issue

I updated the version of com.android.tools.build:gradle to 7.3.1 in /node_modules/react-native-webview/android/build.gradle . This was done by updating the dependencies as

```
dependencies { .... classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1") }
```

This resolves the error above but gives the below error -

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react- native- webview:compileDebugAidl'.
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration webview:debug CompileClasspath'' :react-native-
Could not resolve androidx.webkit:webkit:1.4.0.

Required by:
project :react-native-webview

Could not resolve androidx.webkit:webkit:1.4.0. > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/ maven2/androidx/webkit/webkit/ 1.4.0/webkit-1.4.0.pom'.
Could not GET 'https:// dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/ androidx/webkit/webkit/1.4.0/ webkit-1.4.0.pom'.`